# How do I test a CKEditor 4 text format field with Behat/Mink?

Tags: testing, input-formats

I am using an @javascript test in Behat on CircleCI to check my Drupal 8 site.

When I use the standard `I fill in "my field" with "value"` step, it works for fields with the plain text format, but it fails for fields that use CKEditor.

How can I fill in fields on CKEditor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [doesn't yet have official support in the Drupal Extension](https://github.com/jhedstrom/drupalextension/issues/326).  The linked thread has some examples that use traits.

However, I found [this gist by johnennewdeeson](https://gist.github.com/johnennewdeeson/240e2b60c23ea3217887) to be a faster, easier solution for me, just cut and paste into `FeatureContext.php`:

```
  /**
   * @Then I fill in wysiwyg on field :locator with :value
   */
  public function iFillInWysiwygOnFieldWith($locator, $value) {
    $el = $this->getSession()->getPage()->findField($locator);

    if (empty($el)) {
      throw new ExpectationException('Could not find WYSIWYG with locator: ' . $locator, $this->getSession());
    }

    $fieldId = $el->getAttribute('id');

    if (empty($fieldId)) {
      throw new Exception('Could not find an id for field with locator: ' . $locator);
    }

    $this->getSession()
      ->executeScript("CKEDITOR.instances[\"$fieldId\"].setData(\"$value\");");
  }
```