# How do I test a CKEditor 5 text format field with Behat/Mink?

Tags: testing, input-formats

Drupal 10 is switching from CKEditor 4 to 5.

So, I installed the experimental CKEditor 5 module and am attempting to update my Behat tests to use CKEditor 5.

I am using an @javascript test in Behat on CircleCI to check my Drupal 8 site.

The standard `I fill in "my field" with "value"` step fails for fields that use CKEditor.  For example, for a long text field with the label **Question**, if I add a step:

`And I fill in "Question" with "Will this work?"`

Then I get the error: `Element not interactable`

[As described in this question about CKEditor 4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/298214/how-do-i-test-a-ckeditor-4-text-format-field-with-behat-mink), there is a [gist by johnennewdeeson](https://gist.github.com/johnennewdeeson/240e2b60c23ea3217887) that works for CKEditor 4 (which basically uses JS to find the editor instance and set the data), but it does not work for CKEditor 5 (`CKEDITOR is not defined` error).

So how can I set the value of a text format field in Behat using CKEditor 5?

Comment: CKEditor is just used on the front end, it shouldn't affect the saving of field data - maybe you just need to provide a `format` column as well as the `value`? If you're able to describe a bit better what you mean by "the standard [...] step fails" it could help?

Comment: @Clive Updated with more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [How to get the editor instance object from the DOM element?](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/faq.html#how-to-get-the-editor-instance-object-from-the-dom-element), you can search for `ck-editor__editable` and use that to locate the specific editor instance that you need to manipulate.

The following is a working example.  Note that you have to replaced any underscores with hyphens in the machine name for `$field_hyphenated_machine_name`.

```
  /**
   * Input text using CKEditor.
   *
   * @Then I fill in the wysiwyg field :field_hyphenated_machine_name with :value
   * @Then I enter :value for wysiwyg field :field_hyphenated_machine_name
   */
  public function iFillInWysiwygOnFieldWith($field_hyphenated_machine_name, $value) {
    # https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/faq.html#how-to-get-the-editor-instance-object-from-the-dom-element
    $ckeditor5_drupal_editable_element = "div.form-item-$field_hyphenated_machine_name-display-0-value .ck-editor__editable";

    $this->getSession()
      ->executeScript(
        "
        const domEditableElement = document.querySelector(\"$ckeditor5_drupal_editable_element\");
        if (domEditableElement.ckeditorInstance) {
          const editorInstance = domEditableElement.ckeditorInstance;
          if (editorInstance) {
            editorInstance.setData(\"$value\");
          } else {
            throw new Exception('Could not get the editor instance!');
          }
        } else {
          throw new Exception('Could not find the element!');
        }
        ");
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't that first test be `if (domEditableElement)`?